# List, ArrayList and LinkedList problems?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

I have created two classes, class A that uses a Linked List and class B that uses an ArrayList. Both classes have a method add(), which adds an elements to the LinkedList or ArrayList reciprocally.

My question is: Is it possible to create another class, say C, such that C has its own method add() to add elements to a **LIST**, and class C is the parent of A and B and also that A and B inherit the add() method of class C without overriding it???

P.S: I tried to do this myself but I get an error because I cannot initialize a list in class C. I am using Java

Thank you in advance

Comment: Lets see some code.  And are you using Java?

Comment: What is the programming language you are using??

Comment: Yes I am using java. My add method just basically uses the add methods of ArrayList and LinkedList, I mean add(int index, int number);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Below is the example. I haven't compiled it as I just wanted to give you the idea.

```
class C
{
 protected List sharedList;

 public void add(Object o)
 {
   sharedList.add(o);
 }
}

class B extends C
{
 public B()
 {
   sharedList=new ArrayList();
  }
}

class A extends C
{
 public A()
 {
   sharedList=new LinkedList();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was trying too, but I did not use the same name for the List, like you did with "sharedList". Maybe this is the problem. I am going to try. Thanks :D

Comment: It actually works!!!!! And even if I want to declare abstract class C still it does not create any problems or errors! Thank you so much :D